# in ASP.NET Core MVC, is it possible to add a View folder from outside the project folder?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

The majority of my views are regular `<action>.cshtml` files in the normal `/Views/<Controller>` folder hierarchy. These are source controlled in git and deployed in the usual "rip and replace" way.

However I also use Razor for rendering templates to create HTML emails, and the email .cshtml templates are specific to each client. I therefore want to be able to load and render them from *outside* the Application Root folder, so the client-specific customisations are not lost during deployment.

I have successfully created and registered an implementation of the `IViewLocationExpander` interface and this works for folders inside the Application Root:

```cs
public class EmailViewLocationExpander : IViewLocationExpander
{
    protected readonly String _TemplateFolder;

    public EmailViewLocationExpander( String TemplateFolder )
    {
        _TemplateFolder = TemplateFolder.Trim('/');
    }

    public void PopulateValues( ViewLocationExpanderContext context )
    {
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> ExpandViewLocations( ViewLocationExpanderContext context, IEnumerable<string> viewLocations )
    {
        var result = new List<String>( viewLocations );

        result.Add( $"/{ _TemplateFolder }/Email/{{0}}.cshtml" );
        result.Add( $"/{ _TemplateFolder }/Shared/{{0}}.cshtml" );

        return result;
    }
}
```

It does not seem to work for paths other than Application Root relative, so e.g.  `/../Templates` doesn't seem to work.

I also currently rely on having a custom `_ViewStart.cshtml` for my email templates, and reading the [Mvc source code](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Host/ViewHierarchyUtility.cs) leads me to think that my only option is to implement a custom `IFileProvider` to reference the physical file system outside the current Application Root - is that right and can anyone help me with an example if it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems right to me.  The `ViewLocationExpander` deals with paths relative to the wwwroot folder so it's not going to be useful for specify paths to files outside of that.

Here is a pretty good article on implementing an `IFileProvider`.  The articles demonstrates creating and `IFileProvider` for accessing views stored in a database but reading them from the file system will be even easier.  So it's a great outline of what to consider.  https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/301/loading-asp-net-core-mvc-views-from-a-database-or-other-location

One thing I noted is that the way the way the `IFileProvider` works is pretty cool.  You register your custom implementation as an option to the RazorViewEngine like below and when the ViewEngine needs to get a file, it asks each FileProvider, in order, for that file until one returns it.

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
    string customLocation = @"c:\mylocation\"

    // Add framework services.
    services.AddMvc();
    services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(opts => 
        opts.FileProviders.Add(
            new MyCustomFileProvider(customLocation)
        )
    );
 }
```

So in the end, you basically just implement your `FileProvider` to provide files for some specific url endpoints.  You can obtain them from anyplace you like.

Comment: I had read some old docs which showed Mvc only accepting a single file provider, so I faffed about for a while looking for a CompositeFileProvider (which is now a thing in .NET core) to combine the default and custom locations into a single IFileProvider, but now (I'm using v1.1) it certainly is an IList<IFileProvider> and yes, it was trivially easy to implement as you describe and it works like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: In my case I just created another PhysicalFileProvider for my alternate location:

 services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(
  opts =>
  {
   opts.FileProviders.Add(
    new PhysicalFileProvider( path )
   );
  }
 );