# How to build a project with forms to be used in multiple other MVC projects

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reactjs

My goal is to have an InputMVC project that multiple other MVC projects can use to prevent code duplication and so that if I update the form in the InputMVC project the others are updated as well since they will reference the same InputMVC page.
A quick drawing I made to help convey my wants and need I made.

[image]

My understanding is that cshtml files are not compiled therefore I can not reference them in other MVC projects. I'd also like to have my forms created using ReactJS if at all possible. And another goal is to reuse my controllers since these forms will be updating a Database and I would prefer not to duplicate code and have to update every project every time I need a change.

What is the best route to accomplish this? is it possible to use Reactjs? is it possible to reuse my Controllers as well?

**EDIT**
I should have clarified this previously. The Input project can be whatever it needs to be. It does not have to be an MVC project. Here are my must haves for this project and maybe that will spark an idea for the best path to take.

Requirements

1. Form must use ReactJS
2. Form must be a separate entity to be prevent duplicate code
3. Form will be used as a "partial" inside another MVC project
4. Form will communicate with a DB in some way but I'm not worried about this part

Thanks!

Comment: I would look at maybe creating a Nuget package which you can use to deliver the relevant content into other projects.

Comment: Also consider an architecture change - maybe using a common Web API to allow the projects to access common functionality (e.g. writing to the database) might solve part of the problem.

Comment: I should have clarified that the input project doesn't need to be MVC but i thought it would work best since the other project is MVC already

Comment: Like I say, if you make it an mvc project for the forms that's fine, then you can deliver it into the other projects in the form of a nuget package built from the files in the input project. We did something similar in my last project, the idea was to create an mvc "template" for new projects, with ready made CSS, custom layout page etc all with the company branding ready to go, error handling code included etc etc. If we update the template, we publish a new version of the nuget package and then the other applications can adopt it at a suitable time.

Answer (score 1):

MVC is driven by "convention over configuration."  In other words, it expects controllers to be in a folder called Controllers, it expects views to be in Views/ControllerName or Views/Shared, etc, so this is easier said than done.

If you are gung ho about this, I would create a second MVC project, and in the parent project, add a reference to the newly-created child project.

I believe your parent project will still require controller actions that mirror the actions in the child controller, but these can be simple proxies that just return the IActionResult of the child.  For example:

```
public IActionResult ParentAction()
{
    var childController = new ChildApp.Controllers.ChildController(); // You may need to pass in any dependencies yourself

    return childController.ChildAction();
}
```

This takes most of the headache out of rewriting the controllers, and allows changes in the child project to be reflected automatically.  Now if you go to localhost:1234/Parent/ParentAction, you will see the following error:

```
InvalidOperationException: The view 'ParentAction' was not found. The following locations were searched:
/Views/Parent/ParentAction.cshtml
/Views/Shared/ParentAction.cshtml
/Pages/Shared/ParentAction.cshtml
```

This is because your view is in the child project, not the parent project, and therefore isn't found by the parent controller.  [This article and the referenced link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42298745/in-asp-net-core-mvc-is-it-possible-to-add-a-view-folder-from-outside-the-projec) should give you an idea of how to configure the parent project to reference views in the child project directory to get rid of that error.  Next, I suspect that you will find that all links that are relative to the root such as `~/js/myscript.js` don't work because those are in the wwwroot of the child project, not the parent project.  Perhaps you could set up a symbolic link in your file structure or something to reference the child project from the parent project, but I haven't tested that.

I think that a better solution would be to publish both projects separately, and have the parent project load content from the child project as needed.  You can research reverse proxies to see an example of how this would work.  You can reference scripts and images as needed by using the full URL.  You can frame in content as needed as long as the proper request headers are set (see X-Frame-Options).  The child controllers could also provide data to the parent, acting as an API.

Comment: I should have clarified that the input project doesn't need to be MVC but i thought it would work best since the other project is MVC already.

Comment: Thanks for the information on how to use the controller that will come in handy at some point for this project i believe